# html5 getUserMedia() portrait mode

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, google-chrome

In my browser application (with `AngularJS`) I am making a connection to the webcam via the `HTML5 getUserMedia API`. But for some reason the output stream is always in `landscape mode` and not in `portrait mode`. So I've tried a few things, but I cannot figure out how to get it into portrait mode. Any idea's?

Specs:

AngularJS: 1.6.5

IMac: 27" - MacOS high Sierra

Chrome: 61.0.3163.100 (64-bit)

---

**My code**

```
private static readonly videoOptions = {
    mandatory: {
        minWidth: 1080,
        minHeight: 1920
    }
};

private startCamera(): void {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: MWWebcamController.videoOptions, audio: false})
        .then((stream: MediaStream) => {
            this.webcam = new WebcamStream(window.URL.createObjectURL(stream), stream);
         })
         .catch((exception) => {
             console.error("Could not load the stream. due to: ", exception);
         });
}
```

---

**I've tried**

- Rotating the video via CSS. This kind of works, but the stream won't be rotated with it.
- Settings the `mendatory` property on the videoOptions to `{ height:1920, width: 1080 }`, but this results in an error from the API, `ConstraintNotSatisfiedError { constraintName: "height" }`.

---

I Cannot find any option in the API description or on the web that describes how to use the webcam in portrait mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The iMac (and all desktop devices) has a landscape positioned webcam image sensor so you'll only be able to capture at the sensor's max resolution in landscape mode (e.g. 1920x1080).

Chrome crops and scales the video coming from the webcam to fulfill your constraints so you should get a portrait image if you use a resolution where the height does not go over the sensor's max height (e.g. 270x480 which is 16 times smaller than 1080x1980)

```
var constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: {
    width: { min: 270, max: 270 },
    height: { min: 480, max: 480},
  },
};
```

You can use the [getUserMedia camera resolution finder](https://webrtchacks.github.io/WebRTC-Camera-Resolution/) to find the (landscape) resolutions supported by your webcam & browser combo.

Comment: the link in the answer is a life saver! thank you sir!

Comment: @octavn please can you elaborate on "you should get a portrait image if you use a resolution where the height does not go over the sensor's max height" ?

Comment: @cyrf If your camera's height is x, you can't ask getUserMedia to open the webcam with a height > x. So lower the width rather than raising the height

Comment: @Serus is there a way to know the sensor's height before I ask getUserMedia?

Comment: @cyrf you can get the height in code by using videoHeight, otherwise I believe the dimensions are just your camera's resolution